# listview footer dynamically change state android

Tags: android, listview, footer

I have `ListView` and I want add footer. I easily did it through standard `addFooterView` method. But footer added into end of `ListView` and displayed as part of `ListView` (i.e. if `ListView` items more then placed on the screen then footer outside the screen).
**Why I need it**: I want show button when user interacted with some `View` in `ListView`. And "lift up" `ListView` border at bottom of screen on `(current height value - height value of button)`.
**The problem is**: `onClickListener` required `View` in adapter. And `setContentView` in Activity. I do not get access to the parameters of a button from the adapter to `ListActivity`.

My XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView 
android:id="@+id/watchAddList"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:scrollbars="none"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    style="@style/listViewStyle">
</ListView>

 <include 
  layout="@layout/submit" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And include Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/rl_submit">

<Button 
android:id="@+id/submit"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Сохранить" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPD:** I do It! i used Singleton, and call `Activity` instance in `Adapter` class, then got access to the button properties. Cool!

Comment: Are you creating the 'OnClickListener' in the 'Adpater'?

Comment: Yes, in `GetView` method for `View` in custom row of `ListView`. It's wrong way?

Comment: now will try to move the `adapter` to the class with `Activity`, it should work.